# Using 'out' within lambdas when creating Tasks via Task Parallel Library

Tags: c#, lambda, task-parallel-library

I have the following code that doesn't compile. I get the error

> Cannot use ref or out parameter 'messageLockToken' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression

I admit I'm new to Lambdas and am a bit confused about resolving this one. Does anyone know how I can express the logic below in a compiler acceptable manner?

```
public T Receive<T>(TimeSpan receiveTimeout, out Guid messageLockToken)
{
    // do work
}

public Task<T> ReceiveAsync<T>(TimeSpan receiveTimeout, out Guid messageLockToken)
{
    Task<T> sendQueueMsgTask = new Task<T>(() => Receive<T>(receiveTimeout, out messageLockToken));
    return sendQueueMsgTask;
}
```

Comment: C#, latest implementation per .NET 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your method wouldn't work even if it compiled. That's because when you use `new Task()`, you  always have to call `Start()` on that `Task` (or, alternatively, use `Task.Run()`).

Now, you can't use the `out` parameter here, because it doesn't make much sense. You want to return the `Task` from the method immediately, but that also means returning the `Guid` immediately. Which means there is no way for your call to `Receive()` to actually affect the value of the `out` parameter.

I think using a `Tuple` (as Rawling suggested) or a custom return type is the way to go here:

```
public Task<Tuple<T, Guid>> ReceiveAsync<T>(TimeSpan receiveTimeout)
{
    return Task.Run(
        () =>
        {
            Guid messageLockToken;
            var result = Receive<T>(receiveTimeout, out messageLockToken);
            return Tuple.Create(result, messageLockToken);
        });
}
```

This assumes you actually want to do this, see Stephen Toub's article [*Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) for reasons why doing this is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use an `out` parameter here, instead you could:

- return a `Tuple<T, Guid>` (or use a custom generic class), or
- pass an `Action<Guid>` rather than the `out Guid` (so rather than `ReceiveAsync(ts, out myGuid)` you'd call `ReceiveAsync(ts, g => myGuid = g)`)

(I don't think there's any way you can work around this to still expose an `out` parameter to the caller; an `out` parameter is supposed to be populated when the method returns, but this wouldn't be true in your case.)

Comment: I think your second approach would be confusing, because it's not clear when exactly would be the lambda called.

Comment: @svick I agree, although it'd be the same behaviour as if the `Task`'s lambda allowed an `out`: "set this guid by the time the task finishes".